# Which system call does the Linux file command use?

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, system-calls

Do you know which system call the Linux `file` command uses to determine the type of file?

On the command line, if you use the file command it will reply with something like:

> dev-1:~/$ file download.png
>
> download.png: PNG image data, 724x 724, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

Is this an entire routine that does that?  Or is there a system call that maps to that functionality?

Comment: Use strace to find out.

Comment: @stark I never knew that existed.  I am reading the man page now and I will try it out. thx

Comment: Why do you think that `file` uses system call to determine the type of file? This kind of task can and should be done at user space level, look at `file` source code.

Comment: Most likely it uses `open/read`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the suggestion of @stark I ran the Linux strace command like the following:

```
$ strace file download.png
```

A lot of info is returned (many system calls) but I picked through it and found the core item I was looking for:

```
fstat(3, {st_mode=
```

I searched and [found a man page for fstat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html):

> These functions [lstat, fstatat] return information about a file, in the buffer pointed
> to by statbuf.

There is also a call (or calls) to [pread64()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread64.2.html) which reads from the file descriptor.

Answer (score -2):

Hi I've some helpful Linux file commands for you hope it will be useful below

```
file bobs_file.txt
```

output = bobs_file.txt: ASCII

```
file textfile.tar
```

output = textfile.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)

```
file Picture/
```

output = Pictures/: directory

```
file iuk.png
```

output = iuk.png: PNG image data, 213 x 213, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced

Comment: Hmm...that is multiple examples of one command, not numerous commands.  The file command that I mentioned in my question.  And, I'm asking if you know the System Call (OS API method) that the file command actually runs.